# Finding Conversion Rate

Tags: sql

I have two column tables with subscription result for each project. I need to know the conversion rate for each experiment.

My tables are:

[image]

And my desired result is

[image]

conversion is any user for whom there is a subscription start event in addition to the trial start event (all users have a trial start event). If a user is in multiple experiments at the same time, it’s ok to count them towards the conversion rate of each experiment, also want to only return one row per experiment.

I have done a inner join to get subscription event and experiment id together but able to process further. Any help is appreciated/

My inner join table looks like

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a `left join` with some filtering and aggregation:

```
select e.experiment_id,
       (count(case when experiment_assignment = 'test' then s.user_id end) * 1.0 /
        sum(case when experiment_assignment = 'test' then 1 else 0 end)
      ) as test_conversion_rate,
       (count(case when experiment_assignment = 'control' then s.user_id end) * 1.0 /
        sum(case when experiment_assignment = 'control' then 1 else 0 end)
      ) as control_conversion_rate
from experiment e left join
     subscription s
     on s.user_id = e.user_id and
        s.subscription_event = 'subscription_start'
group by e.experiment_id;
```

Comment: Hey gordon - Thank you of the help. BUt your result gives me 1 or 0 instead of 100%. Can you tell what is the required change to get that output?

Comment: @SumaiyaKhatun . . . You have not specified the database you are using.  Some databases do integer division so 1/2 = 0 rather than 0.5.  I tweaked the code to fix this issue.

Comment: Awesone... Works perfrct .. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select experiment_id,  
       (count(case when experiment_assignment = 'test' and subscription_event = “subscriptipon_start” then user_id end)*100 /  
        count(case when experiment_assignment = 'test' and subscription_event = “trial_start” then user_id )
      ) as test_conversion_rate,  
       (count(case when experiment_assignment = 'control' and subscription_event = “subscriptipon_start” then user_id end) * 100 /  
        count(case when experiment_assignment = 'control' and subscription_event = “trial_start” then user_id end)  
      ) as control_conversion_rate  
from experiment inner join subscription  
     on user_id  
group by experiment_id;
```